# Using condition 3 of the pumping lemma to prove irregularity

Tags: regular-language, automata, computation-theory

So, I've been going through Sipser's book on the Theory of Computation, and one of the exercises is:

> Let B be the language {0^n1^n | n≥0}.
>
> Prove B is not regular.

The book continues to give a proof, using the pumping lemma, letting s=0^p 1^p, s=xyz and testing all three cases; when y is only 0's, only 1's, 0's and 1's. But I can't understand how the latter two options are possible by condition three of the pumping lemma `|xy|≤p`. Does this condition not imply that y can only be 0's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this condition not imply that y can only be 0's?

No, not necessarily. Fix *p*, and let the string be

*w = xyz = 0<sup>1/2 p</sup>1<sup>1/2 p</sup>*

What prevents *x* being the first character, *z* being the last, and *y*  being everything in between?